# Spring boot autoconfiguration AutoConfigureAfter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, jndi

I'm trying to create a fallback ConnectionFactory in case the JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration did not create one for me.

Here's what the class looks like

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ConnectionFactory.class)
@ConditionalOnClass(ConnectionFactory.class)
public class JmsFallbackAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    ConnectionFactory fallbackConfiguration() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        System.out.println("Created: " + activeMQConnectionFactory);
        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }

}
```

What I'm expecting is spring boot starts, some auto configuration is going on, we get to JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration which notices that I have spring.jms.jndi-name set and creates the ConnectionFactory bean.

Then, at some point, I'm expecting it to get to JmsFallbackAutoConfiguration when it should notice that we already have a ConnectionFactory (which was configured by JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration) and move on.

But that's not what happens, JmsFallbackAutoConfiguration always executes and I don't know what I'm missing.

Sample project here https://github.com/apixandru/case-study/tree/master/spring-boot-weblogic-jms/spring-boot-weblogic-jms-war

Comment: Try adding ConnectionFactory.class to method level annotation as well

Comment: @janek, same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JmsFallbackAutoConfiguration` is in the same package as your main application class that's annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. That means that it will be found by component scanning. You need to move it into a separate package so that it isn't in the same package as your main application class or one of its sub-packages.

Comment: You're correct, moving it outside of the main application package fixes the problem. Thank you